# Publishing to different Queues in Rabbit MQ

Tags: php, laravel, rabbitmq

I am using this package: `https://github.com/bschmitt/laravel-amqp` to publish messages to queues and consume them.

There's a problem that when I publish a message to a queue, it is published to all other queues too, but I want the message to be published on that specific queue that I have mentioned.

I have used `topic` exchange, `direct` exchange, used routing keys and bindings, but when I publish a message to a queue, it is published to other queues too.

Here's my `amqp` config:

```
<?php

return [
    'audit_queue' => env('APP_NAME').'_'.env('APP_ENV').'_audit_queue',

    'use' => 'production',

    'properties' => [
        'production' => [
            'host' => env('AMQP_HOST', 'rabbitmq'),
            'port' => env('AMQP_PORT', '5672'),
            'username' => env('AMQP_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('AMQP_PASSWORD'),
            'vhost' => env('AMQP_VHOST', '/'),
            'connect_options' => [],
            'ssl_options' => [
                //'dsn' => 'amqps:', // Comment this line if you're using localized docker
            ],

            //'exchange' => env('AMQP_EXCHANGE', 'amq.topic'),
            'exchange' => 'amq.topic',
            //'exchange_type' => env('AMQP_EXCHANGE_TYPE', 'topic'),
            'exchange_type' => 'topic',
            'exchange_passive' => false,
            'exchange_durable' => true,
            //'exchange_auto_delete' => true,
            'exchange_internal' => false,
            'exchange_nowait' => false,
            'exchange_properties' => [],

            'queue_force_declare' => false,
            'queue_passive' => false,
            //'queue_durable' => true,
            'queue_exclusive' => false,
            //'queue_auto_delete' => true,
            'queue_nowait' => false,
            //'queue_properties' => ['x-ha-policy' => ['S', 'all'], 'x-message-ttl' => ['I', '864000000'], 'x-queue-mode' => ['S', 'lazy']],

            'consumer_tag' => '',
            'consumer_no_local' => false,
            'consumer_no_ack' => false,
            'consumer_exclusive' => false,
            'consumer_nowait' => false,
            'timeout' => 0,
            'persistent' => false,

            'qos' => false,
            'qos_prefetch_size' => 0,
            'qos_prefetch_count' => 1,
            'qos_a_global' => false,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Here's my publishing message code:

```
// console.php
<?php

use Bschmitt\Amqp\Facades\Amqp;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Console Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of your Closure based console
| commands. Each Closure is bound to a command instance allowing a
| simple approach to interacting with each command's IO methods.
|
*/

Artisan::command('queue_1', function () {
    $message = json_encode(['message_1' => 'value_1']);
    Amqp::publish(config('amqp.properties.production.vhost'), $message, [
        'queue' => 'queue_1',
        'exchange_type' => 'direct',
        'exchange' => 'amq.direct',
    ]);

    echo "\nDone queue_1\n";
})->purpose('Display an inspiring quote');

Artisan::command('queue_2', function () {
    $message = json_encode(['message_2' => 'value_2']);
    Amqp::publish(config('amqp.properties.production.vhost'), $message, [
        'queue' => 'queue_2',
        'exchange_type' => 'direct',
        'exchange' => 'amq.direct',
    ]);


    echo "\nDone queue_2\n";
})->purpose('Display an inspiring quote');
```

As you see on the above, I specify it directly that the message 2 be published only on `queue_1`, but when I publish it, it is also available on `queue_1` and `queue_2` but I only want it to be published on `queue_2`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the configuration implemented in your rabbitmq instance? If so, can you share it?